# Сохранения в БД, после удаления Laravel

Tags: php

У меня такой код

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'id' => $userData -> id,
            ],
            [
                'username' => $userData -> username,
                'discriminator' => $userData -> discriminator,
                'avatar' => $userData -> avatar,
                'locale' => $userData -> locale,
                'mfa_enabled' => $userData -> mfa_enabled,
                'refresh_token' => $accessTokenData -> refresh_token
            ]
        );

        foreach ($guildData->json() as $guild) {
            unset($guild['owner']);
            $guild = Guild::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'id' => $guild['id'],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => $guild['name'],
                    'icon' => $guild['icon'],
                    'permissions' => $guild['permissions'] & 0X8 ,
                    'permissions_new' => $guild['permissions_new'],

                ],
            );
            Guild::where('permissions', '=', 0)->delete();

        }

        $userGuild = UserGuild::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'user_id' => $user['id'],
                'guild_id' => $guild['id']
            ]
        );
        dd($userGuild);
```

И на выходе я получаю удаленный id. А мне нужно тот который остался после удаления, с `permissions` равным 8
Тоесть я удаляю строки `permissions` который равны 0. Остаются те которые после битовой оперции равны 8. И id `$guild` и `$user` сохраняю в новую таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам решил

```
if($guild->permissions & 0X8)
{
UserGuild::updateOrCreate(
[
'user_id' => $user['id'],
'guild_id' => $guild['id']
]
);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]